# Why I have two pods of different time creation whereas the deployment config is same for both of them and it was updated recently

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift, config

I am running pods on Openshift using Deployment Configs and putting the replicas as 2. the type of rolling strategy is rolling,

*strategy:
type: Rolling*

When a new update is done, the events show that

*Generated from deploymentconfig-controller
Scaled replication controller "deployment-12" from 2 to 1*
and
*Generated from deploymentconfig-controller
Scaled replication controller "deployment-12" from 1 to 2*

**Expected behaviour:**
The created time should have been same, so that both should be updated/new changes pods. but here they both have different times. Please suggest
[image]

Comment: Try to delete both pods, they will be auto created and to check if it's the same behavior.

Comment: After deleting it starts with same time, but when a new update is sent to deployment config only one of them is updated. The other one just remains as old one.

Comment: can you share the `config yaml` used for creating those `pods`? maybe a condition setted on the `update`

Comment: apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
      app: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xyz
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xyz
        image: usquay.service:${tag}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
  strategy:
    type: Rolling

Comment: Try to add the file config as a `code` in your post, It's better to debug and understand.

Comment: I agree that you need to add the YAML as code in your post. As well as step by step what you are doing. There really isn't enough to troubleshoot with this way. But I'll note that your snippet here says "replicas: 1". Are you just scaling it up and down? If so, you would certainly expect the creation times to be different.

Comment: `apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
      app: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: xyz
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xyz
        image: usquay:{tag}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
  strategy:
    type: Rolling`

Comment: Besides this I have HPA included:
`apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2 
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: cpu-mem-autoscale 
  
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
    kind: DeploymentConfig 
    name: xyz
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10 
  metrics: 
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu 
      target:
        type: AverageValue 
        averageValue: 50m `

Comment: Probably I am missing something between HPA replicas and deployment replicas